# HTML5 localStorage key order

Tags: ajax, html, local-storage

I have some div's on my page coded as

```
<div id="1">Click Me to load corresponding dynamicList</div><ul class="dynamicList"></ul>
<div id="2">Click Me to load corresponding dynamicList</div><ul class="dynamicList"></ul>
<div id="3">Click Me to load corresponding dynamicList</div><ul class="dynamicList"></ul>
<div id="4">Click Me to load corresponding dynamicList</div><ul class="dynamicList"></ul>
<div id="5">Click Me to load corresponding dynamicList</div><ul class="dynamicList"></ul>
```

Now on click of any of the div's, an AJAX call is made which returns the dynamic List as;

```
<li>Some content 1</li>
<li>Some content 2</li>
<li>Some content 3</li>
```

I want to store the above dynamic List in localStorage, after the 1st AJAX call. So I write;

```
var key = $(selectedDiv).attr('id');     
var value = str;     //str = Returned AJAX response of li's
localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

Now on the next page load, I want to append all the dynamicList's (all those which user had clicked earlier) at the right place in the DOM (So an AJAX call is not made for the data during next click)

```
for (i=0;i<localStorage.length;i++) 
{
var key = localStorage.key(i);
    if(key != null) 
    {
    var value = localStorage.getItem(key); 
    $("#"+i).next(".dynamicList").empty();
    $("#"+i).next(".dynamicList").append(value);
    }
}
```

Now there seems to be some issue in the order of the localStorage, as the right dynamicList is not getting appended at the right place.
I guess there is some issue for the line

```
var key = localStorage.key(i);
```

Please let me know how do I fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't rely on the order of `localStorage` keys. You can iterate through all available keys on `localStorage` using `localStorage[n]`, but that refers to a key (string) which can be used with `localStorage[str_key]` or `localStorage.getItem(str_key)`.

In your case, you've confused the index of the `localStorage` key names with the name you assigned to the item. Therefore, don't use the key index, but your value key:

```
for (i=0;i<localStorage.length;i++) 
{
var key = localStorage.key(i);
    if(key != null) 
    {
    var value = localStorage.getItem(key); 
    $("#"+key).next(".dynamicList").empty();
    $("#"+key).next(".dynamicList").append(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfetto....This is what I was looking for...Got slightly confused between localStorage.key(i) and localStorage.getItem(key)

Answer (score 2):

Make a separate object in the `localStorage` to :

- Avoid pollution of the storage space (if you just fill the root node, you'll have a hard time adding extra features later)
- Get sorting back :-)

`localStorage.specificStorage = {}; // Maybe even []`

Comment: Note that objects and arrays cannot be stored in localStorage. Only strings can.

Comment: You have to serialize them to a string using `JSON.stringify`.