# How to limit storage of data onto local storage and retrieve it?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, local-storage

Hi I need to limit the data being added onto my local storage. I only need 5 items to be stored if the user adds the 6th item the first item should be removed. I accomplished that portion but when retrieving it, it retrieves the removed data and skips on the fourth item. Any ideas?

how i set things

```
 var _i = 0 //global;
 storage.setItem(_i, URL);
```

checkLimit

```
if(storage.length >= 5)
{
   var _a = storage.getItem(0);
   storage.removeItem( _a );
   _a += 1;
}
```

When retrieving it

```
for( var _x = 1; _x <= storage.length - 1; _x++)
{
  var _url = storage.getItem(_x);
}
```

## update

oh i forgot to mention that when i use key index to get item it doesnt display the removed data but somehow skips the fourth one.

## update 2

Now it doesn't skip the fourth record but it shows the removed data and doesn't show the last added data. e.g

```
the //first
avengers //second
are //third
coming //fourth
now //fifth
excited //sixth
```

Since i specifically limit it to five (5) `the` should be removed from the list and `excited` should be added. its doing fine but when i close the application and try to retrieve the data it returns

```
the
avengers
are
coming
now
```

and it doesn't shows `excited` Am i making sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on the order of Web Storage keys. Check this question: [HTML5 localStorage key order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340845/html5-localstorage-key-order)
If you want to do this, just use an array object which will be stored in localStorage.

Comment: there's no changes. i still have the problem. note that i'm removing items if the length reaches or exceeds by 5.

Comment: See this http://jsfiddle.net/vJkBQ/4/ of the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606256/push-not-working-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment27386544_18606256. It might helps you with the `getItemIndexById` function.