# push() not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Problem  : `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'push'` in console.

Code in [http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/vJkBQ/1/)

Comment: `push` is a method of arrays, not objects.

Comment: could you debug into the `appendToStorage` function and have a look at the `oldStorage` object after it was loaded from `localStorage`? i.e. via Chrome's developer tools.

Comment: @elclanrs I guess OP knows that, as he is clearly trying to initialize an array on first access `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageName)) || []`

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.slice.call(object)` to convert an object to an array.

Comment: There's a very good chance there is an existing value in localStorage that isn't an array.  Try logging it as @Chips_100 suggested or inspect it in your browsers dev tools.

Comment: I tested your method with a fiddle in IE and Chrome and it should work... http://jsfiddle.net/GHYMm/

Comment: try clearing your localstorage using `localStorage.clear();` maybe you saved in 'cart' something else before by mistake

Comment: if it works what @rps suggested, you should also check the rest of your code if you are setting a localStorage object with key `Cart` elsewhere, as that could lead to subtle bugs

Comment: @Chips_100 :  I added full code in `jsfiddle` link above. Kindly have a look please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change storage item id(Cart) and try again, looks like previously stored item under "Cart" id is not json array as @dc5 suggested in comment section

UPD: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/vJkBQ/4/

HTML

```
<div id='cart'></div>
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add To Cart item 1" />
<input type="button" id="add2" value="Add To Cart item 2" />
```

Javascript

```
//TODO: move from globals
var storageName = 'myCART';

$(document).ready(function () {
    var item = {
        DepartmentID :333,
        CategoryID:117,
        BrandID:19,
        BrandImage:"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
        BrandName:"General",
        ID:711
    };
    var item2 = {
        DepartmentID :123,
        CategoryID:321,
        BrandID:18,
        BrandImage:"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
        BrandName:"Common",
        ID:712
    };

    localStorage.clear(storageName);
    $('#add').click(function(){
       addToCart(item);
    });

    $('#add2').click(function(){
       addToCart(item2);
    });
});

function addToCart(item){
    //by @slebetman   
    var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageName));
    if (! (items instanceof Array) ) {
        items = [];
    }

    var itemIndex = getItemIndexById(items, item.ID);    
    if(typeof(itemIndex) === 'number'){
        items[itemIndex].quantity++;
    }
    else{
        item.quantity = 1;
        items.push(item);
    }

    localStorage.setItem(storageName, JSON.stringify(items));
    console.log(localStorage.getItem(storageName));
}

//find search item index
function getItemIndexById(items, id){
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        if(items[i].ID == id){
            return i;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention about `QuantityInCart`. Let check again in `http://jsfiddle.net/vJkBQ/5/` please.

Comment: I tried your answer, When I click Add on the same item, the quantity did not increase.

Comment: Have you tried http://jsfiddle.net/vJkBQ/4/? because it works for me, if it doesn't work, then can you write, what console says

Answer (score 3):

The expression:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageName))
```

is most likely not returning an array. In which case the statement:

```
var oldStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageName)) || [];
```

is insufficient.

What you should do instead is something like this:

```
var oldStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageName));
if (! (oldStorage instanceof Array) ) {
    oldStorage = [];
}
```

This is a simple way to detect arrays. There are more advanced methods such as checking for the existance of `.length` etc. that detects arrays and array like objects as well as detect arrays in cases where the Array object have been overwritten or works across iframes.

---

### Additional answer:

You've changed the code a lot but the problem is still the same. The line:

```
if (items != null) {
```

is not sufficient to check that items is an array. You should instead do:

```
if ( items instanceof Array ) {
```

to make sure that it really is an array.

Also, in the else block:

```
}else{
    console.log('Cart is empty, preparing new cart array');
    items.push(item);
```

The `console.log` message says that a new array is being prepared. However it lies as the code doesn't initialize a new array but uses the `items` variable as if it was an array. You should instead do this:

```
}else{
    console.log('Cart is empty, preparing new cart array');
    items = [];
    items.push(item);
```

---

### Warning:

However, after all that, please heed the the commenters to my question. If you wrote this whole thing from scratch than doing the things I advised would solve all your problems. But if what you're doing is modifying someone else's code then it's probable that `Cart` was stored in a different format than what you expected.

Please do `console.log(localStorage['Cart'])` before calling `JSON.parse` and post your results here. The problem is with **your** local storage on your browser and cannot usually be reproduced on other people's machines.

Comment: this is a correct and good explanation of the problem (+1). But OP should also check, what was in `localStorage` before under key `Cart`, and if he sets it elsewhere in his code. Otherwise this may lead to subtle bugs.

Comment: An alternative would be `if (! (oldStorage instanceof Array) ) {
    oldStorage = [ oldStorage ];
}` if the old value shall be used even if it's not an array.

Comment: Please kindly have a look at my `jsfiddle` above, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Does

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageName))
```

always return an array? If so, the issue is that not all browsers support the push method. You can add use this snippet to add it if it is missing:

```
if(!Array.prototype.push){
    Array.prototype.push=function(x){
        this[this.length]=x;
        return true
    }
};
```

This code is just a start, you can definitely improve it

Comment: `push` is supported by all browsers I know, but nice suggestion :D

Comment: Which browser does not support `Array#push`?

Comment: Some older versions of IE do not support it, and the implementations in many browsers have some quirks. See http://hexmen.com/blog/2006/12/push-and-pop/

Answer (score 1):

You can use you can invoke [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) on an object using [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ArvFK/)

#### JavaScript

```
function appendToStorage(storageName, data){
    var oldStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageName)) || [];
    Array.prototype.push.call(oldStorage, data);
    localStorage.setItem(storageName,JSON.stringify(oldStorage));
}
```

Comment: yes, you `can`. I would not recommend this, as it will most likely not produce a result that OP would be expecting; or looking for...

Comment: My apologies, I thought the OP was trying to push data to local storage.

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse` returns an object or `null`. So here you don't know if you have an object or an Array.

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageName)) || [];
```

You can use this instead:

```
function appendToStorage(storageName, data){
    var oldStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageName)) || {};
    if (oldStorage != null){
        $(oldStorage).extend(data);
        localStorage.setItem(storageName,JSON.stringify(oldStorage));
    } 
}
```

$.extend() will add your item to another JSON object. Info [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

Comment: there is no such thing as a `JSON object`. Did you mean that `JSON.parse` will always return an object? This is not the case, as `JSON.parse(null)` will return null.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'item' is not an array, and you cannot use a push method with it.

Comment: as OP is trying to start with an array, this is probably not helpful.`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageName)) || [];`

Comment: @Chips_100: This is probably the correct answer. Otherwise `push` would work. `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageName))` most likely is returning something which is not an array.

Comment: Your comment is the correct answer. But `item` is of course an object and `push` is never called on it in OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

Object do not have 'push' method,you can do like this!

```
function appendToStorage( storageName, data ) {
    var oldStorage = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( storageName ) ) || {},
        push = Array.prototype.push;
    push.call( oldStorage, data );
    // oldStorage.data = data;
    localStorage.setItem(storageName,JSON.stringify(oldStorage));
}
```

Comment: as OP is trying to initialize with an array, it should have a push method. Now you basically made a change which makes it an object...

Comment: var push = Array.prototype.push;   var obj = {};
push.call(obj, "hello");