# localStorage - use getItem/setItem functions or access object directly?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Are there some benefits of using the methods defined on the localStorage object  versus accessing the object properties directly? For example, instead of:

```
var x = localStorage.getItem(key);
localStorage.setItem(key, data);
```

I have been doing this:

```
var x = localStorage[key];
localStorage[key] = data;
```

Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: i believe they are exactly the same.

Comment: localStorage is global so you should cache the properties in local var if you want to access it multiple times.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh huh? What does that have to do with the question

Comment: Apologies, I meant localStorage is global so I guess provided functions might have performance edge if you want to access it multiple times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Square bracket syntax vs functions for localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383880/square-bracket-syntax-vs-functions-for-localstorage)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Not really, they are, basically, exactly the same.  One uses encapsulation (getter/setter) to better protect the data and for simple usage. You're supposed to use this style (for security).

The other allows for better usage when names(keys) are unknown and for arrays and loops. Use `.key()` and `.length` to iterate through your storage items without knowing their actual key names.

I found this to be a great resource : http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

This question might provide more insight as well to some: [HTML5 localStorage key order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340845/html5-localstorage-key-order)

### Addendum:

Clearly there has been some confusion about encapsulation. Check out this quick [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)). But seriously, I would hope users of this site know how to google.

Moving on, encapsulation is the idea that you are making little in and out portals for communication with another system. Say you are making an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) package for others to use. Say you have an array of information in that API system that gets updated by user input. You could make users of your API directly put that information in the array... using the `array[key]` method. OR you could use encapsulation. Take the code that adds it to the array and wrap it in a function (say, a `setArray()` or `setWhateverMakesSense()` function) that the user of your API calls to add this type of information. Then, in this `set` function you can check the data for issues, you can add it to the array in the correct way, in case you need it `push`ed or `shift`ed onto the array in a certain way...etc. ***you*** control how the input from the user gets into the actual program.  So, by itself it does not add security, but allows for security to be written by you, the author of the API. This also allows for better versioning/updating as users of your API will not have to rewrite code if you decide to make internal changes. But this is inherent to good [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) anyhow. Basically, in Javascript, any function *you* write is a part of *your* API. People are often the author of an API *and* it's sole user.  In this case, the question of whether or not to use the encapsulation functions is moot. Just do what you like best. Because only you will be using it.

(Therefore, in response to Natix's comment below...)

In the case here of JavaScript and the `localStorage` object, they have already written this API, they are the author, and we are its users. If the JavaScript authors decide to change how `localStorage` works, then it will be much less likely for you to have to rewrite your code if you used the encapsulation methods. But we all know its highly unlikely that this level of change will ever happen, at least not any time soon. And since the authors didn't have any inherent *different* safety checks to make here, then, currently, both these ways of using `localStorage` are essentially the same. Except when you try to get data that doesn't exist. The encapsulated `getItem` function will return `null` (instead of `undefined`). That is one reason that encapsulation is *suggested* to be used; for more predictable/uniform/safer/easier code. And using `null` also matches other languages. They don't like us using `undefined`, in general. Not that it actually matters anyhow, assuming your code is good it's all essentially the same. People tend to ignore many of the "suggestions" in JavaScript, lol! Anyhow, encapsulation (in JavaScript) is basically just a shim. However, if we want to do our own custom security/safety checks then we can easily either: write a second encapsulation around the `localStorage` encapsulate, or just overwrite/replace the existing encapsulation (shim) itself around `localStorage`. Because JavaScript is just that awesome.

PT

Comment: As I said, one uses encapsulation (getter/sitter)... so that should of be obvious.. its the functions that start with "get" or "set"... if you understand encapsulation. And the other is the way that uses `.key()` and `.length` to iterate.

Comment: So how exactly do the methods _better protect the data_ and improve _security_ if _they are, basically, exactly the same_?

Comment: I'm not sure that the lacking of that information is worthy of a downvote. here.  Seeing that it was not requested by the OP. And as I said, the answer is..Not really.  There is not any real intrinsic  safety difference in these two ways of javascript. The nomenclature of sending everything to a function (encapsulation) allows for a portal for that transaction. If you wanted, you could rewrite that portal.. which is something else well beyond this context.  But it should be obvious how that level of control could be used to increase safety. Assuming you know encapsulation, this is all obvious.

Answer (score 10):

I think they are exactly the same, the only thing the [documenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) states is:

> Note: Although the values can be set and read using the standard
>   JavaScript property access method, using the getItem and setItem
>   methods is recommended.

If using the full shim, however, it states that:

> The use of methods localStorage.yourKey = yourValue; and delete
>   localStorage.yourKey; to set or delete a key **is not a secure way with**
>    **this code**.

and the limited shim:

> The use of method localStorage.yourKey in order to get, set or delete
>   a key **is not permitted with this code**.

Comment: not exactly the same, getters return `null` whereas direct object properties return `undefined` for missing keys

Answer (score 7):

One of the biggest benefits I see is that I don't have to check if a value is undefined or not before I JSON.parse() it, since getItem() returns NULL as opposed to undefined.

Comment: One should always wrap `JSON.parse` with *try/catch* blocks when working with the *localstorage* since the values returned are unreliable and might not parse

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't use the "dot notation" like window.localStorage.key you are probably OK, as it is not available in Windows Phone 7. I haven't tested with brackets (your second example). Personally I always use the set and get functions (your first example).

Answer (score 0):

**Well, there is actually a difference,** when there is no local storage available for an item:

1. `localStorage.item` returns *undefined*
2. `localStorage.getItem('item')` returns *null*

One popular use case may be when using `JSON.parse()` of the return value: the parsing fails for *undefined*, while it works for *null*

Comment: Duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22388478/188031