# Square bracket syntax vs functions for localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

What is the difference between the following two snippets of code? Is the square bracket syntax an old, deprecated syntax? When I first used localStorage, all the documentation I found definitely said to use the square bracket syntax, but now I can't find any documentation on it at all.

The documented syntax:

```
localStorage.setItem('hello', 'world');
localStorage.getItem('hello'); // world
```

The square bracket syntax:

```
localStorage.hello = 'world';
localStorage.hello; // world
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) says about it:

> Although the values can be set and read using the standard JavaScript property access method, using the getItem and setItem methods is recommended.

Comment: I think your comment about globalStorage is misleading because the question is about localStorage.

Comment: Thank you @Phillip, it was confusing indeed. I just edited.

Comment: Do you know why it is reccommended?  I know you are quoting, but do you know the thinking behind it?

Comment: It's not documented use, so its behavior may vary on each implementation. Also, they probably want a getter/setter to be able to inject behavior when data changes or is read. @user1167442

Comment: The documentation does not seem to state that any more