# How to save into localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im doing a simple form that save the informationinto locastorage, it save the information one time and if you try again it will save the informationbut replace the old one. Is there a way to keep adding the info into locastorag without replacing the old information.

**HTML :**

```
 <h2>Entry</h2>
        <hr><br>
        <form>
          <label for="title">Title:<br></label><input type="text" name="title" id="title"><br><br>
          <label for="comments">Comments:<br></label><textarea cols="40" rows="4" id="comments"></textarea><br> 
          <button type="reset" class="button-class" id="add">Submit</button> <br><br>
          <a onClick="clearStorage()" style="cursor:pointer"> --> Clear Local Storage <-- </a>
        </form> 
        <div class="entry">

        </div>
```

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#add').click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var addText = $('input[name=title]').val();
        var addComment = $('textarea#comments').val();
        $('.entry').append($('<div class="in-ent"><br><h3>Title:</h3><p> ' + addText + '</p><br><h3>Comments:</h3><p> ' + addComment + '<br></p><br></div>'));
        document.getElementById("title").value = "";
        document.getElementById('comments').value = "";

        save(addText,addComment );
    });
}); 

function save(addText,addComment )
{
    var addText =addText;
    var addComment = addComment;
    var myArrayObject = [];
    var entry = new Object();
    entry.title = addText;
    entry.comments = addComment; 
    myArrayObject.push(entry ); 
    localStorage.setItem("Entry", JSON.stringify(myArrayObject));
} 

function clearStorage() {
    console.log("Clearing local storage."); 
    localStorage.clear();
    window.location.href = "index.html";
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jqj82wks/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store an array instead of simple variable :

```
var addText =addText;
var addComment = addComment;
var myArrayObject = [];
var entry = new Object();
entry.title = addText;
entry.comments = addComment; 
myArrayObject.push(entry ); 

//First entry when localStorage not exist
if ( localStorage.getItem("Entry") == null )
{
    localStorage.setItem("Entry", JSON.stringify(myArrayObject) );
}else{
    //get array stored in localstorage
    var entries_array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Entry"));

    //Add new entry to the array
    entries_array.push(entry);

    //Store array
    localStorage.setItem("Entry", JSON.stringify( entries_array ) );
}

console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Entry")));
//Output Array of objects 
//[Object, Object, Object]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a set method, simply use :

`localStorage.lastname = "Smith";`

OR

`localStorage["lastname"] = "Smith"`

**[html5 webstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)**.

Comment: But I want to identify title with comments, so I can keep a record of entries.

Comment: He's using [`.setItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) for a reason.

Comment: @Blazemonger and that reason is?

Comment: @Pedro, not sure what you mean.. you can still use your JSON `localStorage["Entry"] = JSON.stringify(myArrayObject));`

Comment: If for no other reason, using getters and setters is a good habit to be in (while referencing [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/) is a really bad habit to be in). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092715/localstorage-use-getitem-setitem-functions-or-access-object-directly

Comment: @Blazemonger no reason, im just learning but I don't know what is the correct way to do it.