# gameover page - Can't save to local storage

Tags: javascript, cordova, local-storage

I want to add a high score to my game. Right now I have this:

```
var score = 0;
```

The score variable works but whenever I get like points so total of 60 points it says the high score is still zero when checking it using `console.log(highscore)`.

I have this to store the high score:

```js
localStorage.bestscore = score;
var bestscore = localStorage.bestscore
```

and retrieve the saved data as that

```js
<script>
         document.getElementById("bestscore").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('best'); 
</script>
```

```html
<h1>Your Score is <span id="bestscore">0</span></h1>
```

but there is something wrong ! please help :) !

Comment: There is a typo error in your code. Change to: localStorage.getItem('bestscore');

Comment: i will recheck it one second

Comment: still not working idea

Comment: Please provide more detail about how and where you are testing your code.

Comment: I use XAMPP to set local host and test my code there do u want to have a look ? please add me to skype @drusama2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created this file to show it - works as expected. I have my console set to show local / session storage so i can see when the number gets amended and that works as expected too,.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body onload="set_score()">
    <p>The highest Score so far is: <span id="bestscore"></span></p>
                <input type="text" id="score" value="" >
                    <button type = "button" onclick="score()">score</button>
<script>
function set_score()
    {
        var score=0;
        localStorage.setItem("high_Score",score);
        document.getElementById("bestscore").innerHTML=score;
    }

function score(){
    var score=parseInt(document.getElementById("score").value);
    var highScore = localStorage.getItem("high_Score");
    if(score > highScore){localStorage.setItem("high_Score",score)};
    var new_highScore = localStorage.getItem("high_Score");
    document.getElementById("bestscore").innerHTML=new_highScore;
    }
</script>
</body> 
</head>
</html>
```

Just copy this into a notepadd++ document save it as html and run it in a browser. Hope it helps Gav

Answer (score 2):

To store something in the localStorage, you have to use 'setItem'

```
localStorage.setItem('bestscore', score)
```

Then to retrieve it, use

```
localStorage.getItem('bestscore')
```

More about the functions:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem

Comment: What is not working ? When you set innerHTML, you use 'best', not 'bestscore'.

Comment: please see last answer from @gavgrif

Comment: See: [localStorage - use getItem/setItem functions or access object directly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092715/localstorage-use-getitem-setitem-functions-or-access-object-directly)

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` has two methods `getItem` and `setItem`.
Here's an example :

```
localStorage.setItem('bestScore', score);
var bestScore = localStorage.getItem('bestScore');
```

Answer (score 1):

the following will set the highscore into localStorage, then when a score is made,will get the highscore from local storage and if the new score is higher than the existing highscore, will overwrite the highscore with the new value. Hope this helps. Note that this is only part of the code - needs to be put into a function that is called when a score is made.

```
var score=0;
localStorage.setItem("high_Score",score);
var highScore = localStorage.getItem("high_Score");
if(score > highScore){localStorage.setItem("high_Score",score)};
```

and then to display it:

```
var highScore = localStorage.getItem("high_Score");
document.getElementById("bestscore").innerHTML=highScore;
```

Comment: sorry - screwed up the last line - shpuld be fine now

Comment: Seems to be excellent solution but not working on my local preview mood it needs a host ?

Comment: I just put together a div with an input and button that calls the score function and it works as expected. Inital value of score and highscore is 0 and then after inputting a value into the input box and calling the function - the highscore loalstorage value is amended if the new score is higher than the existing high score

Answer (score 0):

here are the functions: on page load- call set_score() to initialise values and then on the entry of the number into the input field (with the id of "score") - call score() and it should work.

```
function set_score(){
    var score=0;
    localStorage.setItem("high_Score",score);
    document.getElementById("bestscore").innerHTML=score;
}

function score(){
    var score=parseInt(document.getElementById("score").value);
    var highScore = localStorage.getItem("high_Score");
    if(score > highScore){localStorage.setItem("high_Score",score)};
    var new_highScore = localStorage.getItem("high_Score");
    document.getElementById("bestscore").innerHTML=new_highScore;
}
```

works as expected on my pooter

Comment: I have used localhost but still not working ... can we chat through skype and tell me please how it worked for you ? @drusama2

Comment: hi - i put this together for you - works well on my pooter - just copy the document save it as html and run it in a browser. I have my console window set to show local / session storage so can see the values set in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.localStorage`:

```
var score = 0;
window.localStorage.setItem('bestScore', score);
var bestScore = window.localStorage.getItem('bestScore');
```

I hope helps!