# Are all of these 3 methods of setting a property in localstorage valid?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I know only one way of setting localstorage in HTML5

`localStorage.name = "Peter Martin";`

But, in the following discussion I found that there are 2 other ways to set localstorage.

[localStorage - use getItem/setItem functions or access object directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092715/localstorage-use-getitem-setitem-functions-or-access-object-directly)

```
localStorage.setItem(city, "New York");
localStorage[country] = "USA";
```

However, when I tried all 3 in the example below, seems the first works fine but issues with the other 2 methods. Can someone explain me out if all 3 methods are valid?

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

<button onclick="alpha()">Click Me</button>

<script>
function alpha(){
localStorage.name = "Peter Martin"; 
localStorage.setItem(city, "New York");
localStorage[country] = "USA";
}
</script>

</body> 

</html>
```

As, there is some sandbox issue with StackOverflow, I am posting error image, as below:

[image]

Comment: `localStorage` is an object, so dot and array notation might work with it. But in my understanding, the correct way is to use `.setItem` and `.getItem`. Also as for the error, `city` should be in quotes

Comment: @Rajesh so should `country`

Comment: `localStorage.name` is the same as `localStorage['name']`. That's nothing to do with localstorage, it's just how [javascript property accessors work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: @George error snapshot showed error for city only. So I assumed, it can be a variable. But you are correct.

Comment: May want to [Read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comes down to basic JavaScript syntax.

When you call `localStorage.setItem(city, "New York");`, you are referring to an identifier, `city`, which is not defined in the current scope. You should either define a variable named `city`, or just use the string `"city"` directly.

The same goes with `localStorage[country] = "USA";`. `country` is not defined in this scope, so the JavaScript engine throws an error.

Answer (score 3):

> Can someone explain me out if all 3 methods are valid?

Yes they are (ish). localstorage like pretty much everything in Javascript is an object. You can access properties in an object in two ways:

```
object.property
object['property']
```

See [Property accessors in Javascript MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). So there is no reason why you can't access properties of the localstorage object using property accessors as the above.

```
localStorage.setItem("city", "New York");
```

Is a method on the localstorage object that:

> The setItem() method of the Storage interface, when passed a key name
>   and value, will add that key to the storage, or update that key's
>   value if it already exists.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)

So this is a valid way to *"add that key to the storage, or update that key's
value if it already exists"*. Your having problems with this method because your passing an incorrect parameter `city` that doesn't exist. I believe you meant `"city"`. [As covered in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46170949/542251)

Answer (score 1):

You can break it down into

1> properties or values

```
localStorage.name = "Peter Martin"; 
localStorage["name"] = "Peter Martin";
```

The 2nd version allows you to use a JavaScript variable. But is harder to read because one needs to determine what value is in the variable.

IE

```
var tag= "name";
localStorage[tag] = "Peter Martin";
```

and

2> methods or functions that get / set value; etc.

```
localStorage.setItem("name", "Peter Martin");
```

vars allowed,

```
var obj = "name";
var value = "Peter Martin";
localStorage.setItem(obj, value);
```

With methods there are the .prototype goodies, which include things like .bind() that allows you to say do something when you call setItem. But generally when I want to do something after setting a property I do it on the very next line; I Keep it simple and readable.

I'm not sure why I would ever need to use the methods. But, on a modern system there should be no measurable difference in speed.

Maybe using methods would allow two tabs open at the same time to synchronize data between tabs?

There are situations in loops that change values of properties and either methods or properties works, I don't recall the details; but unlikely to need that with a localStorage string.

---

Now I recall, why a method or function is sometimes needed.

This fails using a property. (always returns 10 the last value of i)

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var n = elements.length;    // assume we have 10 elements for this example
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function() {
        console.log("This is element #" + i);
    };
}
```

This works using a function

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var n = elements.length;    // assume we have 10 elements for this example
var makeHandler = function(num) {  // outer function
     return function() {   // inner function
         console.log("This is element #" + num);
     };
};
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = makeHandler(i+1);
}
```

So if you are going through a long list and want to cancel then return to it using localStorage use the method.

---

Even though the localStorage may not require a method. Our subconscious brain recognizes patterns. And the loop with a property value pattern triggers a warning, anxiety because of how long it takes to find it, even though the details are not recalled. Though it would work since it does not store a reference to the variable it only stores static strings.

To program at max speed, people need to follow the patterns that they know work. Methods resolve the value of the value at the time the method was called.

Answer (score -2):

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

<button onclick="alpha()">Click Me</button>

<script>
function alpha(){
localStorage.name = "Peter Martin"; 
localStorage.setItem("city", "New York");
localStorage["country"] = "USA";
}
</script>

</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: and what is this supposed to mean?

Comment: Code without an explanation is pretty pointless (most of the time, and especially in this case)

Comment: BTW, Ironically his answer is right. The only thing is that should have added comments, that need to add the city and country within quotes to define as strings.

Comment: @Deadpool if that is the correct solution, this post should be closed as a typographical mistake. I thought it was more about the correct way to use, hence have not voted yet.

Comment: @Deadpool I agree with Rajesh, I thought this question was more about explaining How/why the code can work in this way, not fix this code.

Comment: @Rajesh - Actually I never did know that they should have been within Strings. I thought this should have worked. The answer clearly gets me, that No! The key should be within strings, else it is not correct. Also, provides to me that there is not 1, but 3 ways to define or retrieve localStorage values. That buys some respect! ;)

Comment: @George - Yes brother! I agree. Without explanation its meaningless.

Comment: @Deadpool The reason why dot and array notation works is because `localStorage` is an object. But is it the correct way? There must be a reason why developers added APIs like `setItem` and `getItem`. None the less, it falls to your personal preference as to how you wish to use. My suggestion is to use APIs and not other ways