# How to update localstorage object value from index and key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, local-storage

I need this solution for my project. its very important for me.
i want to update object value with key and index, from local storage
FOR
my cart application.

(Decrease button for product quantity in cart)

Exmp.

```
function decreaseQuantity(index) {
  var oldQty = localStorage.cart[index].quantity;
  var newQty = oldQty - 1;
  localStorage.setItem(cart[index].quantity, newQty);
}
```

Comment: You're not using [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) properly.

Comment: That's not how you get or set to localStorage. Please go through [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). localStorage uses string key-value pairs. How are you setting the `cart` to localStorage?

Comment: @jeto what's the truth of it ?

Comment: Look here: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Pay special attention to the way  values are retrieved (with `.getItem`) and also the note: *The keys and the values are always strings*. You'll need to stringify your array and parse it when you retrieve it.

Comment: I think he's got the doc's URL by now, guys :)

Comment: @adiga 

function saveCart() {
        if ( window.localStorage)
        {
            localStorage.cart = JSON.stringify(cart);
        }
    }

Comment: You need to use `setItem` like this: `localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart))` and not directly assign it `localStorage.cart`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#Example

Comment: @adiga Actually, [you can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092715/localstorage-use-getitem-setitem-functions-or-access-object-directly), though it's not particularly recommended.

Comment: @Mark Meyer thanks you too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't store complex object in `localStorage`, you can store data as `string` only.

If you want to store the cart object to `locaStorage` , you need to serialize it as string using  `JSON.stringify` and store it like following.

```
window.localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
```

Note: here 'cart' is the key.

To get back, change it and store back, you need to do like following.

```
 var data = window.localStorage.getItem('cart');
        if (data != null) {
            let cart= JSON.parse(data);
              cart[index].quantity = cart[index].quantity -1;
             window.localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

its worked for me @PSK thanks for your efforts
@adiga I guess I made a logic error. thank you too, for your interest !