# Auto pre-select dropdown value from URL address

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown, html-select

I'm using the dropdown select menu which redirects users to selected cities. I have searched for this topic everywhere and tried many solutions found on stackoverflow but each of them did not work. In many cases it even disabled the redirection of my dropdown. So I am posting a new question. Hopefully that someone could solve my problem.

Problem: When I visit URL I see select delivery city - non value option. It should show the selected city based on URL address.

My URL looks like this /kategoria-produktu/CITY U SELECT (/kategoria-produktu/cadca/)

To sum up: When u visit url /kategoria-produktu/cadca the dropdown should be preselect on current url and display Čadca.

Any ideas how could I solve this?
Thank you very much!

CODE

JS

```
if(location.href.indexOf(localStorage.country) == -1){
location.href = localStorage.country
}

function formChanged(form) {
var val = form.options[form.selectedIndex].value;
if (val !== 'non-value') {
if (localStorage) {
localStorage.country = val;
}

if (!location.href.indexOf(val)) {    
location = val;
   }
  }
 }
```

HTML

```
 <form name="form1">
 <select id="saleTerm" onchange="formChanged(this); location = 
 this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" NAME="country" SIZE="1">
 <OPTION VALUE="non-value">Select delivery city</option>
 <OPTION VALUE="/kategoria-produktu/cadca/">Čadca</option>
 <OPTION VALUE="/kategoria-produktu/brno/">Brno</option>
 <OPTION id="bratislava" VALUE="/kategoria-produktu/bratislava/">Bratislava</option>
 </select>
 </form>
```

Comment: 1) You know your HTML's invalid, right? Missing closing tags. 2) It would be good if you could sort your JS indentation out - makes it much easier to read and try to understand your problem.

Comment: @Mitya edited, hope now you could understand it

Comment: @Mitya thank you for HTML tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a bunch of little things need to change here for you to get what you want. I'll try to write them all down:

1. You should access localStorage using getItem and setItem like in the [localStorage MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
2. Use an event listener instead of the inline `onchange` attribute, it's much cleaner.
3. You probably want to use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) instead of indexOf since you are looking for a substring (country) in a string (href), indexOf won't do this for you.
4. I used `location.pathname` since you really only care about the path, there are better ways to get the exact path parameter you want.
5. No need to use a `<form/>` as far as I can see from the code you shared.
6. I removed `/kategoria-produktu/` from the option's value attribute since its repetitive and just placed it once in the js
7. You should change the value of the `select` to the city you want as the default selected. You can do this by parsing out the city from the path and setting it as the `value` attribute on the select

I think that's it, here is an example using those points above.

```js
const PREFIX = "kategoria-produktu";
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  let countryInStorage = localStorage.getItem("country");

  if (countryInStorage && !location.pathname.includes(countryInStorage)) {
    location.href = `/${PREFIX}/${countryInStorage}`;
  }

  document.getElementById("saleTerm").addEventListener("change", formChanged);
  setDefaultOption();
})

function setDefaultOption() {
  let countryPath = location.pathname.split("/")[2];

  if (countryPath) {
    document.getElementById("saleTerm").value = countryPath;
  }
}

function formChanged() {
  let selectedCountry = this.value;
  if (selectedCountry !== "non-value") {
    if (localStorage) {
      localStorage.setItem("country", selectedCountry);
    }

    if (!location.pathname.includes(selectedCountry)) {
      location.href = `/${PREFIX}/${selectedCountry}`;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="saleTerm" name="country">
  <option value="non-value">Select delivery city</option>
  <option value="cadca">Čadca</option>
  <option value="brno">Brno</option>
  <option value="bratislava">Bratislava</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Andrew! I tried your solution but It still does not work :// It works like before. Redirects me to the category of the city but Its not filled with selected value in select dropdown. Still see the select city option.

Comment: Maybe if there is any option to add selected into option by value so it should looks like <option selected value"cadca">Čadca</option> when you are at the Čadca url it may fix the problem.

Comment: so you want the dropdown to select the same city that is in the URL?

Comment: yes, the solution which nmina provided works well but when I dont select any city it gets me to /undefinied url string which is not good

Comment: so the main domain example.com gets you redirect to example.com/undefined

Comment: @LuboMasura see my edit, looks like you don't need local storage so I also removed that from my answer to reduce confusion

Comment: I do need local storage because now system does not remember my last selected url and does not reedirect me there. So returning visitors always have to choose option and that is exactly what I do not want to happen. So local storage should be there. :) try to edit it with tht pls :) thank you!

Comment: Thats it! Thank you so much Andrew!

Comment: Good answer - except there is (normally) no compelling reason to prefer `getItem()`/`setItem()` over normal object interfacing (i.e. dot or square-bracket syntax) with `localStorage`, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13093116/1352288) discusses.

Comment: @Mitya MDN specifically suggests to use the web storage API (such as getItem() ) in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API so that's why I suggested it.

Comment: Sure, of course MDN is going to document the methods if they exist. I'm just saying (as was the answer I linked to) that there is no benefit in the vast majority of situations to using them over the more direct method.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you are looking onto showing the proper option from the select element based on the URL.

Look at the example below. It basically runs a process on page load and when the DOM is ready (hence `DOMContentLoaded`) to check if an option based on URL exists in the select options and picks that. You may have to update your logic depending on the URL structure. The example below assumes your URL is always formatted like `http://your.domain.com/kategoria-produktu/<city>/`.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // find the option based on the URL.
  let option = document.querySelector("#saleTerm > option[value='" + location.pathname + "']");

  // assign the option value to the select element if such exists.
  if (option) {
    document.querySelector("#saleTerm").value = option.value;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This did the thing!

Comment: one more question, why does this primary gets me to /undefinied URL when I did not choose anything? Is there any chance to change /undefinied to something else?

Comment: You're welcome! And about your question, the `/undefined` probably happens when you're setting the location.href, in which, referring to your sample code, could be on this line `location.href = localStorage.country`. You can add a condition to either set a default value or to not execute the redirection when localStorage.country ends up being undefined or null.